# Javascript + DOM - links within same page

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a existing page with several entries(divs), and I loop trough all of them to fetch the wanted content(headers) to create a list of links.

In the process I assign each header a unique ID, but I can't seem to get my list of links to "connect" to the specific entries.

Javascript:

```
var entries = document.getElementsByClassName('entry');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var heading = entries[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
    var addId = heading.setAttribute("id", "#entry" + i);

    var x = heading.getAttribute("id");

    var headingText = document.createTextNode(heading.firstChild.nodeValue);
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute("href", x);
    link.appendChild(headingText);

    li.appendChild(link);
    ul.appendChild(li);

}

var target = document.getElementById('newdiv');
target.appendChild(ul);
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

When I hover over my list with links, they show the link as supposed - but nothing happens when I click it. If I inspect the DOM I can also see that all of the headers got assigned a unique ID.

Comment: You are using the `#` the wrong way around. The element ids have to be _without_ the hash, and the anchor links that should point to them with one. `<foo id="bar">` and `<a href="#bar">` is the correct way of using it.

Comment: Also just write `heading.id = "entry" + i;` - no need to use `.setAttribute()`.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. I was having a brain-meltdown for a couple of hours, thanks alot for the quick responses!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove # from :

```
var addId = heading.setAttribute("id", "entry" + i);//("id", "#entry" + i)
```

and Add # to :

```
link.setAttribute("href", "#"+x);//("href",x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sometimes even the most simple things can mess with your mind, I guess :)

Comment: Agree :) 

Happy Coding.

Comment: No need to use setAttribute for href nor id. Why use a function when the dot notation is available.

Comment: @EasyBB: I just corrected his code with minimal changes (thats what he actually asked in the question). Your inputs are helpful for performance optimization and better understanding. Thanks :)

Comment: I understand that, though you should point out to the OP that using a function when say `link.href = ...` and `heading.id = "entry" + i` work faster and are better suited for readibility.